# How does a where clause in a view affect how the db engine processed DML with respect to indexed views?

Tags: sql-server, materialized-view

Imagine a database where you have an indexed view aggregating data from 2 tables, a dataset table and a datapoints table (master/detail).

When a dataset is first created it has a status of LOAD. The expectation is millions of rows will be added to the DataPoints table so we want to avoid updating the aggregate stats at this stage. When loading is complete the status of the dataset will be changed to READY. At this stage, we want the aggregates in place. There is still potential for a dataset in the READY state to get more Datapoints, but it will be much less common.

The DDL is below:

```
create table dataset
(
   ID int not null ,
   Name nvarchar(50) not null,
   Status nvarchar(10) not null,
   constraint PK_Dataset primary Key (ID)
);


Create table DataPoints
(
   id int not null  ,
   DataSetID int not null,
   Amount money not null,
   constraint PK_DataPoints primary Key (ID)
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_DataPoints_FK ON DataPoints
(
    DataSetID ASC
);

ALTER TABLE DataPoints  WITH CHECK 
  ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Datapoints_Dataset] FOREIGN KEY([DataSetID])
  REFERENCES Dataset (ID);

Create View Totals WITH schemabinding
   as

Select
  DataSet.ID,
  DataSet.Name,
  Count_Big(*) as DataSetCount,
  Sum(DataPoints.Amount) as DataSetTotal
From
  dbo.DataSet
Inner Join
  dbo.DataPoints
On
  DataSet.ID = DataPoints.DataSetID
where
  DataSet.Status = 'READY'
Group by
    DataSet.ID,
    DataSet.Name;
  
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1
  ON Totals (ID);
```

Let's populate the Dataset table like so:

```
INSERT INTO DataSet
    ([ID], [NAME], [STATUS])
VALUES
    (1, 'EAST', 'READY'),
    (2, 'WEST', 'READY'),
    (3, 'SOUTH', 'READY'),
    (4, 'NORTH', 'LOAD');
```

Also see here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed676c/3

Let's say we insert rows into DataPoints with a DatasetID of 4.

Will the database engine be smart enough to know it doesn't need to update the indexed view?

Let's say we insert rows into DataPoints with a DatasetID of 3.

Will the database engine be smart enough to just take the existing aggregates and update the totals and count only  referencing the new row? or will it need to read the DataPoints table and re-aggregate all rows with DatasetID = 3?

Lets say we run:

```
UPDATE DataSet Set Status='READY' where DatasetID = 4
```

Will the database engine do a complete table scan of DataPoints and refresh the aggregates for every dataset? Or is it smart enough to only scan or seek for the rows related to DatasetID 4?

Comment: TLDR; Answer to 1: it cannot know unless it looks up the parent table, but once it does that then the rest of the plan will be skipped because 0 rows. Answer to 2: yes that's the whole point of the `GROUP BY` restrictions on indexed views, to make efficient updates. Advise to add `INCLUDE (Amount)` to the non-clustered index, and possibly a filtered index `WHERE (STATUS = 'READY')` to the parent table